# selenium chrome driver select certificate popup confirmation not working

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am automating tests using selenium chromewebdriver 3.7. Whenever I lauch the site, I get a certificate selection popup like the one below[image]

However I am not able to click on the OK button. These are the options I have tried

```
 //I have tried getWindowHandle like this  
 String  handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
        this.driver.switchTo().window(handle);
```

---

```
//I have alos tried switching and accept
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

---

```
//I have also tried to force the enter key like this
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

---

```
 // I also tried this way
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 keyboard.nextLine();
```

All my trials have failed. How can I click on OK on this popup window?
This is the closest solution I found which is not working [Link here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5408)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I was able to solve it by using the robot, creating function for the url and passing it to a different thread.

```
    Runnable mlauncher = () -> {
    try {

      driver.get(url);
     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    };

public void myfunction {
 try {

   Thread mthread = new Thread(mlauncher);
   mthread.start

  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

 } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: Can you explain, flow of this call ?

Comment: Where does the `robot` come from? I assume you mean the [Selenium Robot class](https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html)?

Comment: Oups, the `Robot` class comes from AWT

Comment: can you please explain this?

Comment: It seems that the answer `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` is more actual at the moment.

Comment: `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` seems to be not a good option if we want to use different certificates in our tests. Maybe changing values of `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` dynamically during tests, before running browser, could be a workaround? However, I am afraid that it could require higher user permissions to edit registry.

Comment: Have followed the same approach, worked for windows based chrome but failed on my docker chrome image. Is there's anything different needs to be done?

Answer (score 9):

I also had problems with accepting the warning for using a signed certificate. The solution of @eskoba worked like a charm. The functions are NOT final, because I let the enter button press for 10 times. I made this, because the webdriver needs a long time until it actually calls the url. In the meantime he starts pressing already.

**In Python**:

```
def threaded_function():
    #Calls the website
    browser.get(url)

def threaded_function2():
    #Presses 10 times
    for i in range(0,10):
        pyautogui.press('enter')

#Calling the website and pressing 10 times in the same time
thread2 = Thread(target = threaded_function2)
thread2.start()

thread = Thread(target = threaded_function)
thread.start()
```

Comment: Great answer! For a clearer definite, some important import goes like: import threading  import pyautogui  then define a browser i.e. browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe PATH'); then you can put above code into work. One more comment here is that you can put a time.sleep(10) in the threaded_function2 so that it would allow 10 seconds for example to let the url load.

Answer (score 5):

If still actual, I had same issue on Mac, and solution was simple:

- for chrome is set `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` policy like that:

  ```
  defaults write com.google.Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls -array-add -string '{"pattern":"[*.]example.com","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"**cert issuer**"}, "SUBJECT":{"CN": "**cert name**"}}}'
  ```
- for safari:

  ```
  security set-identity-preference -c "**cert name**" -s "**example.com**"
  ```

then use it in code like 
`subprocess.call()` in python

Comment: The policy can be enabled also via registry and other approaches in multiple operating systems.

```

See the policy docs https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls

Comment: This is how I configured this in a `.reg` file:
```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls]
"1"="{\"pattern\":\"https://example.com\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"example.com\"}, \"SUBJECT\":{\"CN\":\"Alex McSubjectUser\"}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be, use **Sikuli** to click on OK button in the certificate.

Steps:

1. Take screenshot of OK button and save it.
2. Download sikuli-script.jar and add it to Project's Build path.
3. Take a screenshot of the UI Element to be clicked and save it locally.
4. Add the following code to the test case.

   `Screen s=new Screen();
    s.click(“image name”);`

Other functions Sikuli provides can be found [here](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sikuli-tutorial-part-1/).

Answer (score -2):

You can also skip being prompted when a certificate is missing, invalid, or self-signed.

You would need to set `acceptInsecureCerts` in `DesiredCapabilities` and pass that when you create a driver instance.

for example, in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
```

Comment: Your solution is not correct, because it is not referred to this specific problem. You want to bypass the insecure certificate warning from your browser, but this what @user4237435 asked for was to bypass the warning to actually use a signed certificate.
With your solution you get rid of that only: https://www.veterinaryha.org/images/2018/Blog/June/non-secure-http-warning-message.png