# Handling Chrome browser 'Select a Certificate' windows popup

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This certificate can be disappeared with either pressing mouse button or pressing entering in Keyboard. But I couldn't handle it with selenium.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C29Hp.png)

This is my login process script:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOMQB.png)

Appreciate any suggestion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512058/selenium-chrome-driver-select-certificate-popup-confirmation-not-working you can check this

Comment: Create manualy new browser profile, import your certificate in this new profile and set up to automaticaly use the imported certificate. Finaly launch selenium with the browser profile.