Certificate is not being accepted with Chrome version 128.X.X.X
I am using Selenium with Java to test a web application.
When accessing the web app manually, I get a popup to select a certificate file. There is only 1 cert file in this popup, which is also available in Personal -> Certificates in my cert manager.

To disable this popup and remove the need to manually accept the cert when running automated tests, I have done the following:

Added the ChromeOption:
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

Added DesiredCapabilities:
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);


I am not sure if this information is relevant but I have recently upgraded the Chrome browser version to 128.0.6613.85. The popup appears and waits for me to manually accept it. Even when run headless, it waits to be accepted and then fails.
I tried using the ChromeOptions:
--disable-machine-cert-request
--disable-signin-frame-client-certs
Is there a solution for this?

The options you are setting have nothing to do with the dialog you show. That dialog is allowing you to select a local certificate to present to the server in order to authenticate. The options you are setting have to do with how Chrome treats certificates presented by the server.

The solution given in this question worked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49963537/22447496


create manualy new Chrome profile dedicated to selenium
in this new profile import your certificate and set up to always use it
verify manualy the certficate usage
use the profile in selenium, see Load Chrome Profile using Selenium WebDriver using java


Each time I access the website manually, I get this popup. So it is not an issue of whether the certificate is saved in the chrome profile.

check step #2 again
